# ProcessBuilder removes " from the command in powershell

Tags: java, powershell

Short: I am trying to run a command in the ProcessBuilder:

```
public static String execute(String cmd) {
    System.out.println(cmd);
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("powershell.exe", cmd);
    StringBuilder fullStatus = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    Process reg;
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    try {
        reg = builder.start();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(reg.getInputStream()));
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
          fullStatus.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        reg.destroy();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return fullStatus.toString();
}
```

If i execute following command:

```
Get-WmiObject -Query " SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer WHERE Default=$true"
```

it ignores the " in my file.

> Get-WmiObject : Es wurde kein Positionsparameter gefunden, der das
>   Argument "*" akzeptiert. In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
>   + Get-WmiObject -Query  SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer WHERE Default=$true
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `ProcessBuilder` is removing the quotes from your `cmd` argument.  You can work around this in two ways:

Escaping the quotes:

```
public static String execute(String cmd) {
    cmd = cmd.replace('"',"\\\"")
    ...
```

Calling the command with arguments that don't need quotes:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Printer -Filter { Default = True }
```